# Spinner inside a fragment using kotlin: none of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: android, kotlin

I've been trying to put a spinner inside a fragment, codying with kotlin , but I haven't made it yet.

This is how I've been trying.

I hope you guys could help me.

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding: RutinaBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.rutina, container, false)
        binding.check.setOnClickListener{view : View ->
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_rutina_to_menu_final)

        }

        val numero_series = resources.getStringArray(R.array.number_series_string)

        if (binding.numSeries != null) {
            val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this ,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, numero_series)
            binding.numSeries.adapter = adapter


        return binding.root
    }

}
```

Comment: You could add a comment to the line where the error is occuring.

Comment: what is the actual error?

Answer (score 5):

`ArrayAdapter` takes a `Context` as its first parameter, but a `Fragment` is not a `Context`. You should use the `requireContext()` method to get a `Context`

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(requireContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, numero_series)
```